# hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto in persistence.xml is ignored

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have following persistence.xml in my application:

```
<persistence-unit name="mydb" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider" />
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider" value="filesystem" />
        <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet" value="UTF-8" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I'm not setting hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto to any value. I expect that there's no hbm2ddl stuff done when starting the application, but hibernate checks and creates tables.
I also tried setting the value to an empty String "", but that also didn't help.

When I increase hibernate log level to "debug" I see following:

```
----------> Parent Classloader: org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@5985910 
excludeUnlistedClasses: false
JTA datasource: null
Non JTA datasource: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource@41c38891{ConnectionPool[defaultAutoCommit=null; defaultReadOnly=null; defaultTransactionIsolation=-1; defaultCatalog=null; driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver; maxActive=20; maxIdle=20; minIdle=5; initialSize=5; maxWait=30000; testOnBorrow=true; testOnReturn=true; timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=5000; numTestsPerEvictionRun=0; minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=60000; testWhileIdle=false; testOnConnect=false; password=********; url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl; username=myuser; validationQuery=null; validatorClassName=null; validationInterval=30000; accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed=true; removeAbandoned=false; removeAbandonedTimeout=60; logAbandoned=false; connectionProperties=null; initSQL=null; jdbcInterceptors=null; jmxEnabled=true; fairQueue=true; useEquals=true; abandonWhenPercentageFull=0; maxAge=0; useLock=false; dataSource=null; dataSourceJNDI=null; suspectTimeout=0; alternateUsernameAllowed=false; commitOnReturn=false; rollbackOnReturn=false; useDisposableConnectionFacade=true; logValidationErrors=false; propagateInterruptState=false; }
Transaction type: RESOURCE_LOCAL
PU root URL: file:/C:/apache-tomcat-7.0.39/webapps/mywebapp/WEB-INF/classes
Shared Cache Mode: UNSPECIFIED
Validation Mode: AUTO
Jar files URLs []
Managed classes names []
Mapping files names []
Properties [
    hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion: true
    hibernate.cache.provider_class: org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider
    hibernate.connection.useUnicode: true
    hibernate.connection.CharSet: UTF-8
    hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: 
    hibernate.search.default.directory_provider: filesystem
    hibernate.show_sql: true
    hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans: true
    hibernate.connection.characterEncoding: UTF-8]
```

and further on:

```
2015-11-19 03:25:07.511 [DEBUG] (localhost-startStop-1) org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl  - Instantiating session factory with properties: {java.vendor=Oracle Corporation, sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD, [...] hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true, org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.jarsToSkip=, java.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation, hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update, [...]
```

It seems, that the property is overwritten by something else.

I have no hibernate.cfg.xml file.

What do I have to do so that hibernate does not any hbm2ddl stuff when starting the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the solution: It was the definition of the EntityManager:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Afetr setting "generateDdl" to "false" no DDL stuff is done when starting the application.